# Trisect $\pi/5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

By writing π/15 in terms of π/5 and π/3, show that it is possible to
trisect π/5 and also possible to construct a regular 15-gon.

I'm not sure how breaking $\pi/15$ down like this would help me show that it's possible to trisect $\pi/5$... Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

(I'm starting to suspect that there is a typo -- missing a 1 in $\pi/5$ to make it 15 in the denominator)

Comment: You can construct $\pi/3$ and $\pi/5$, so you can construct $\pi/3+\pi/5=8\pi/15$. Not quite what you wanted though....

Comment: $\frac{1}{15}= \frac{2}{3}- \frac{3}{5}.$

Comment: Do you know that ${\pi\over3}$ and ${\pi\over5}$ are constructible?

Comment: I don't know about constructible, but I thought $\pi/3$ was not trisectable.?

Comment: You do not trisect $\pi/3$.  It's $\pi/5$ you're trisecting, using $\pi/3$ itself (not any trisection thereof) as an auxiliary angle.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, do you mind elaborating? I understand what you're saying but I'm unsure on how that shows $\pi/5$ is able to be trisected.

Comment: @james https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIV/propIV16.html.

Comment: maybe you are confused because you think you have to perform some kind of operation called trisection to a pi/5 angle, while it is not the case at all. "trisect pi/5" is a bad wording for "construct a pi/15 angle with ruler and compass".